# Can OAuth2 be used in Google Cloud Client Libraries?

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

- I would like to use `.net` variant of Google Cloud Client Libraries ([Resource Manager](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Cloud.ResourceManager.V3) for creating new project, for example).
- I wouldn't like to use neither service account credentials nor ADC.

Can I somehow pass existing `OAuth` credentials (access token, obtained for appropriate scope) to the client library to authenticate the given user?
(Or) do I need any authentication client library?

Briefly looked at the `ProjectsClientBuilder` class, but seems heavy generated (also as the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.ResourceManager.V3/latest/Google.Cloud.ResourceManager.V3.ProjectsClientBuilder)), meaning it's a bit harder to find any hint.

Comment: The google .net client libraries allows for authorization to more then 150 apis.  Which one?   Do you want an example for Oauth2 with a random api or do you have a specific api you are trying to connect to?    Most of the cloud APIs only have examples for Service accounts, while most of the Google Apis api's only have examples for installed applications.    What type of app are you creating?

Comment: Have you even bother to read the question? The API of interest is Resource Manager. Although it might not matter, I guess the vast majority of them use the same methods, one of which is OAuth (additionally to service account or ADC). I can, of course, post direct request to given service endpoint using the properly formatted body and authentication header with OAuth token, but I wanted to use the cloud client libraries (which are currently being recommended by the Google).

Comment: Unforuantatly there are so many apis i dont have them all memorized.   Any special method you want?  There seams to be three different versions of this api.    If im going to try to put together a sample for you it would be nice to know which call you are looking for.

Comment: I would like to create a new project (probably resulting in a POST to `https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/create`) using the provided `OAuth` access token for authorization (and using the recommended and heavily generated google cloud client libraries from the mentioned nuget).

Comment: That was fun thanks 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example shows how to authorize the [Google cloud resource manager](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/authorizing) API using Oauth2 for an installed app.

```
// Key file from google developer console (INSTALLED APP)
var PathToInstalledKeyFile = @"C:\Development\FreeLance\GoogleSamples\Credentials\credentials.json";

// scope of authorization needed for the method in question.
var scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform";

// Installed app authorizaton.
var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.FromFile(PathToInstalledKeyFile).Secrets,
    new []{  scopes },
    "userName",
    CancellationToken.None,
    new FileDataStore("usercreds", true)).Result;

var client = new ProjectsClientBuilder()
{
    Credential = credential,
}.Build();

var projects = client.ListProjects(new FolderName("123"));
```

Note for a web application the code will be different. Web authorization is not the same with the client library.  I havent tried to connect any of the cloud apis via web oauth before.

Comment: Thanks. So the solution is to use Builder's Credential property, which is imported from the base class (`ClientBuilderBase`). Looks like the `ICredential` implements also `ITokenAccess` which looks like the way to pass the token.

Comment: Let me know if you have any issues with it I dont actually have anything on that API so its just returning empty.   but it would be interesting to hear if it works.

Comment: Yes, I will check and let you know. In the meantime I started to experiment with the older one `Google.Apis.CloudResourceManager.v3` which seems less convoluted, but still the method of passing the credentials is over-complicated.

Comment: Using the `ICredential` works as expected, thanks for the hint. See my post below.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, only thing needed is to initialize `Credential` property in the project builder prior the `Build()`.

Just for the completeness:

```
    // when using Google.Apis.CloudResourceManager.v3
    public class Program
    {
        private static async Task OlderMethod(string oAuthToken)
        {
            using var service = new CloudResourceManagerService();

            var id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")[..8];
            var project = new Google.Apis.CloudResourceManager.v3.Data.Project
            {
                DisplayName = $"Prog Created {id}",
                ProjectId = $"prog-created-{id}",
            };
            var createRequest = service.Projects.Create(project);
            createRequest.Credential = new OlderCredential(oAuthToken);

            var operation = await createRequest.ExecuteAsync();
            // ...
        }
    }

    public class OlderCredential : IHttpExecuteInterceptor
    {
        private readonly string oAuthToken;

        public OlderCredential(string oAuthToken) { this.oAuthToken = oAuthToken; }

        public Task InterceptAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", oAuthToken);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

In the end the newer one is simpler, just returning the token, no need to modify the request itself:

```
    // when using Google.Cloud.ResourceManager.V3
    public class Program
    {
        private static async Task NewerMethod(string oAuthToken)
        {
            var client = await new ProjectsClientBuilder
            {
                Credential = new NewerCredential(oAuthToken),
            }.BuildAsync();

            var id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")[..8];
            var project = new Project
            {
                DisplayName = $"Prog Created New {id}",
                ProjectId = $"prog-created-new-{id}",
            };

            var operation = await client.CreateProjectAsync(project);
        }
    }

    public class NewerCredential : ICredential
    {
        private readonly string oAuthToken;

        public NewerCredential(string oAuthToken) { this.oAuthToken = oAuthToken; }

        public void Initialize(ConfigurableHttpClient httpClient) { }

        public Task<string> GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync(string? authUri, CancellationToken cancellationToken) => Task.FromResult(oAuthToken);
    }
```